# How do I assign armor and other special items to characters?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

After completing a quest I received the Dragonhelm armour and there's an event message telling me it is available to be assigned to a character - but how do I do that?

I can't see the item anywhere, and there are no notifications in the UI suggesting I should open a particular menu (like the "!" that appears on the technology icon when you are not researching anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a legendary item, its receiving automatically on that lord/hero who owned that, after 1 turn of course. On the other hand, if a lord or hero gets an item and he actually has one equipped of that kind of item (armor, sword, ect), you can do it on the character details, clicking on the bottom left corner. I also think you can do this by clicking on the skills menu and then switching on the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after some more poking around: you need to select one of your lords or heroes, then open the "Character Details" details screen, using the button in the bottom-left corner (the face with the magnifying glass).

Then you can equip the armour by choosing it from the dropdown menus on the character's details screen.